# I need to open up a file by loop + array then use preg_match to check the contents how?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, preg-match

ok I'm suppose to call up a certain txt file then using loop then check the contents let's say if the first eight words are set how it should be and if it is an actual email address blah blah....

I don't have much because I'm totally stuck but this is what I have for now....

```
$fileContents = file("./aaa/aaa.txt);

foreach($fileContents as $row)
{

}
```

totally don't have much.....because I'm totally confused....
and let's say in that aaa.txt this is what's inside

```
a456789,baloney,tony,t_baloney@shaw.ca
a221111,lasty,firsty,e@mail.ca
```

but I have to then check if the first part is start with a and exact 6 numbers after no more or less and also check if the email is valid...like email contains xxxxx@xxx.xx

anyone able to give me a clue, a hand or help me out please?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: If it is csv syntax then use php's `fgetcsv()` function to read it line by line. Then you can apply a regex with pattern extraction on each line. You _really_ should start reading documentation on php...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($fileContents as $i => $row) {
  $cols = explode(',', rtrim($row, "\r\n"));
  if (!(preg_match('/^a\d{6}$/', $cols[0]) && preg_match('/^[-._a-z0-9]+@[-.a-z0-9]+$/', $cols[3]) {
    echo "Bad line #".$i.": ".$row;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a noob in php...let me digest :P

Comment: The RE for email is not doing very complete validation. If you search SO, you should be able to find better. This just shows the general structure.

Comment: but thanks for the general structure ^_^ the => helped me a lot....never used => before....

Comment: wait I'm confused again....I was playing around to make myself understand => more by taking $i=> away then try echo $row and $cols...but I just realized even if I take $i => out...it still works and $row and $cols are the same....and I missing something?

Comment: `$i` is just used to print the line number in the error message.

Comment: Right. In an indexed array, the keys are the indexes.